# How to use lambda expression to select specific item?

Tags: c#, .net, lambda

I am just learning lambda expression and I want to use lambda expression to select any specific item.
Here, I want to select a person with key = 1 so that selectedOne = "sanjay"

```
    var people = new Dictionary<int, string>();
    people.Add(1, "sanjay");
    people.Add(2, "roshan");
    people.Add(3, "neejesh");
    people.Add(4, "deep");   
    var selectedOne = people.Select(x => x.Key == 1);
```

How should I construct my lambda query?

Thanks!

Comment: Filter first with `Where` and then fetch the result with `Select`.

Comment: Why use LINQ with a dictionary, instead of a lookup, eg: `people[1]` ?

Answer (score 8):

`Dictionary` is implements `IEnumerable` of `KeyValuePair` that contains `Key` and `Value` property:

```
var selectedOne = people.First(x => x.Key == 1).Value;
```

You are using wrong LINQ method. `Select` is used to project some values (transform one into another). You need to filter instead (search via specified key).

**But... using LINQ to select dictionary key is not efficient**. Better is:

```
var selectedOne = people[1];
```

It's amortized O(1) against O(n) - huge difference.

Answer (score 3):

You want to use a Where call to filter the result set to the person you want, then use Select to define the results you want, e.g.

```
var selectedOne = people.Where(x => x.Key == 1).Select(x => x.Value).First();
```

It would be much more efficient to perform the look up via the dictionaries index as suggested by pwas

Answer (score 0):

The code should be something like:

```
var selectedOne = people.Single(x => x.Key == 1);
```

This will give you the keyvalue pair. If you want the string only:

```
var selectedOne = people.Single(x => x.Key == 1).Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are mixing the concept of `Lambda Expression` and `LINQ`. You have used the `Lambda Expression`. But if you have to use `LINQ` the first condition is the data collection you are using must implements `IEnumerable` interface e.g. `LIST<T>` Now write your `LINQ` code as:

```
var selectedOne = (from p in people
                  select p
                  where p.Key == "1").Single()
```